# How to pull data from tags based on other tags

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following example document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage">
<Form1095CUpstreamDetail RecordType="String" lineNum="1">
<RecordId>1</RecordId>
<CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
<irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
<EmployeeInfoGrp>
<OtherCompletePersonName>
<PersonFirstNm>JOHN</PersonFirstNm>
<PersonMiddleNm>B</PersonMiddleNm>
<PersonLastNm>Doe</PersonLastNm>
</OtherCompletePersonName>
<PersonNameControlTxt/>
<irs:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
<irs:SSN>123456790</irs:SSN>
</Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
<Form1095CUpstreamDetail RecordType="String" lineNum="1">
<RecordId>2</RecordId>
<CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
<irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
<EmployeeInfoGrp>
<OtherCompletePersonName>
<PersonFirstNm>JANE</PersonFirstNm>
<PersonMiddleNm>B</PersonMiddleNm>
<PersonLastNm>DOE</PersonLastNm>
</OtherCompletePersonName>
<PersonNameControlTxt/>
<irs:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
<irs:SSN>222222222</irs:SSN>
</EmployeeInfoGrp>
</Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
</n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>
```

Using Nokogiri I want to extract the value between the `<PersonFirstNm>`, `<PersonLastNm>` and `<irs:SSN>` for each `<Form1095CUpstreamDetail>` based on the `<RecordId>`.

I tried removing namespaces as well. I posted a small snippet, but I have tried many iterations of working through the XML with no success. This is my first time using XML, so I realize I am likely missing something easy.

When I set my XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'
submission_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('1094C_Request.xml'))
submissions = submission_doc.remove_namespaces
nodes = submission.xpath('//Form1095CUpstreamDetail')
```

I do not seem to have any association between the `RecordId` and the tags mentioned above, and I am stuck on where to go next.

The fields are not listed as children for the `RecordId`, so I can't think of how to approach obtaining their values. I am including the full document as an example to make sure I am not excluding anything.

I have an array of values, and I would like to pull the three tags mentioned above if the RecordId is contained within the array of numbers.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]", then reduce your input XML to the absolute, bare, minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything else beyond that only wastes our time helping you. Also, take the time to format variables inside the text. That helps those helping, and those searching for similar solutions in the future, understand the question.

Comment: The XML is invalid, which can lead to problems parsing. Mismatched tags force the parser to do fixups, in an attempt to recover and try to provide something useful, but that process can result in tags being missing. You'll need to figure out how to fix the XML prior to parsing it if you want to ensure your code has a good starting point. Nokogiri `submission_doc.errors` should return "Opening and ending tag mismatch: Form1094CUpstreamDetail line 3 and Form1095CUpstreamDetail" after parsing.

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan I should have paid more attention to those errors, it turns out the source was manipulating the files before providing them and causing my xml issues. 

I have edited the above to try and comply with your request as I was able to use the info you and the accepted answer provided to move forward. 

Lesson learned and apologies for the headaches and issues caused.

Comment: While your edit helps, please note that your XML is still invalid. A really quick and easy test is to pull just the XML into an editor that can beautify/reindent, and have it reformat the XML. When it's finished look at the last couple nodes and see if they're correctly nested. Or, copy/paste it into an XML validator. Your code should never need to modify syntactically correct XML prior to parsing, instead use the parser for everything. If the XML isn't syntactically correct at the start then contact the people who generate it and tell them to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Your last point is where I should have started and a valuable lesson on how to address similar situations in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri makes it pretty easy to do what you want (assuming the XML is syntactically correct). I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage">
  <Form1095CUpstreamDetail RecordType="String" lineNum="1">
    <RecordId>1</RecordId>
    <PersonFirstNm>JOHN</PersonFirstNm>
    <PersonLastNm>Doe</PersonLastNm>
    <irs:SSN>123456790</irs:SSN>
  </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
  <Form1095CUpstreamDetail RecordType="String" lineNum="1">
    <RecordId>2</RecordId>
    <PersonFirstNm>JANE</PersonFirstNm>
    <PersonLastNm>DOE</PersonLastNm>
    <irs:SSN>222222222</irs:SSN>
  </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
</Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>
EOT

info = doc.search('Form1095CUpstreamDetail').map{ |form|
  {
    record_id:       form.at('RecordId').text,
    person_first_nm: form.at('PersonFirstNm').text,
    person_last_nm:  form.at('PersonLastNm').text,
    ssn:             form.at('irs|SSN').text
  }
}
pp info
# >> [{:record_id=>"1",
# >>   :person_first_nm=>"JOHN",
# >>   :person_last_nm=>"Doe",
# >>   :ssn=>"123456790"},
# >>  {:record_id=>"2",
# >>   :person_first_nm=>"JANE",
# >>   :person_last_nm=>"DOE",
# >>   :ssn=>"222222222"}]
```

While it's possible to do this with XPath, Nokogiri's implementation of CSS selectors tends to result in more easily read selectors, which translates to easier to maintain, which is a very good thing.

You'll see the use of `|` in `'irs|SSN'` which is Nokogiri's way of defining a namespace for CSS. This is documented in "[Namespaces](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces)".

Comment: Thank you. After going back to the source and getting the fixed xml this provided a much more readable script that is easily expanded.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the xml validator reports error

> The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0'.

so you must set this default xmlns to "".

You can use this code.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('1094C_Request.xml'))

doc.namespaces['xmlns'] = ''

details = doc.xpath("//:Form1095CUpstreamDetail")

elem_a = ["PersonFirstNm", "PersonLastNm", "irs:SSN"]

output = details.each_with_object({}) do |element, exp|
  exp[element.xpath("./:RecordId").text] = elem_a.each_with_object({}) do |elem_n, exp_h|
    exp_h[elem_n] = element.xpath(".//#{elem_n.include?(':') ? elem_n : ":#{elem_n}"}").text
  end
end
```

**output**

```
p output
# {
#   "1" => {"PersonFirstNm" => "JOHN", "PersonLastNm" => "Doe", "irs:SSN" => "123456790"},
#   "2" => {"PersonFirstNm" => "JANE", "PersonLastNm" => "DOE", "irs:SSN" => "222222222"}
# }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This got me exactly where I needed.